# A question about a continuous function that satisfy certain limits at $\pm\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

I got this question:

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}$ and $\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}$ exist and are real numbers.
>   Prove that there exist constants $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, |f(x)|\leq ax^2+b$.

I tried showing it using the definition of limits at $\pm\infty$ but I wasn't able to proceed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $|f(x)/x^2| \leq a$ for some $a$ and for all $x \in [-N,N]^{c}$ (for some large $N$) by definition of limits at $\pm\infty$. Now in $[-N,N]$ $f$ is cont. and hence bounded, so $|f(x)| \leq b$ for some $b$. Thus, $|f(x)| \leq ax^2+b$

Comment: How does that follow from the definition of limits at infinity?

Comment: OK, now that you made the edit your statement does follow from the definition of the limit.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: ah- so that was your way of saying that there should be an edit :). Thanks.

Comment: Oh, and you should say "by definition of limits at plus or minus infinity".

Comment: Yes, thanks for the answer.